# Spring: why normal and @ResponseBody controller generate different code?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, rest

I have two classes:

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------ */
@Entity
@Table(name="ABC")
@NamedQuery(name="Abc.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Abc c")
public class Abc implements Serializable {

    @Id @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="def_id", nullable=false)
    private Def def;

    // getters and setters...

}
/* ------------------------------------------------------ */
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEF")
@NamedQuery(name = "Def.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Def c")
public class Def implements Serializable {

    @Id @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "def")
    private List<Abc> abc;

    public Def() {
    }
    // getters and setters...
}
/* ------------------------------------------------------ */
```

`Abc` have ManyToOne association with `Def`.

I need to generate HTML table and JSON from class `Abc`. I have following code in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/page", method=RequestMethod.GET) // HTML table
public String getPage(Model model) {
    List<Abc> abc = AbcManager.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("abc", abc);
    return "abc";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/json", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) // JSON (REST API)
public @ResponseBody List<Abc> getJson() {
    List<Abc> abc = AbcManager.findAll();
    return abc;
}
```

If I go to url `/page`, everything is ok. But if I go to url `/json` I get this error:

```
Oct 11, 2014 11:01:19 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/project] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: net.example.project.entity.Def.nodes, could not initialize proxy - no Session] with root cause
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: net.example.project.entity.Def.nodes, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Where is the problem? I do not want include list of all `Def` in output. "Normal" controller do it right for me, but rest controller not. Why?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Only guessing because I do not know exactly what `/page` displays, but IMHO it is because in `/page`, you only display a list of `Abc` object, each with its `Def`, and I assume that the loading of `Def` is eager (not lazy). So when you pass the model to the view all has been fetched from database

But Jackson is much more *clever* and tries to go as deep as it can through all relations. So it receives a list of `Abc`, but each has a `Def` (fine like above), but the `Def`has a list of `Abc`, and Jackson tries to find the list to put in the output of the `Def`. As the transaction is ended, Hibernate has no Session, so the Exception.

You will have to add annotations for Json serializing in Def to state that the `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "def") private List<Abc> abc;` should not be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted Jackson JSON mapper.

Now I am creating a JSON manually using **org.json.simple** and everything works good.